# Why neo4j-ogm not saves relations to embedded neo4j-database?

Tags: java, spring-boot, neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I try to get a working system of an embedded tomcat-server with spring-boot, joinfaces and the embedded [neo4j](https://neo4j.com/)-graph-database with the object-mapping ogm. Everything seems to work fine. I commit my sources to https://svn.riouxsvn.com/circlead-embedd/circlead-embedded/

The problem is that all [neo4j-ogm](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm)-examples (see i.e. http://www.hascode.com/2016/07/object-graph-mapping-by-example-with-neo4j-ogm-and-java/) show that @Relationship works with ogm. But when i test it with

```
@NodeEntity
public abstract class GenericNode<T> implements INode<T> {

    @GraphId
    public Long id;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String label;

    @Relationship(type = "PARENT_OF", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    public Set<T> parents = new HashSet<T>();

    @Relationship(type = "CHILD_OF", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    public Set<T> children = new HashSet<T>();

    ...
```

then all relations seem not to be written in the database, because the lines

```
    Role rp = new Role("Role 1");
    Role rc = new Role("Role 2");
    rc.addParent(rp);
    session.save(rc);
    Iterable<Role> roles = session.query(Role.class, "MATCH (x) RETURN x;", Collections.<String, Object>emptyMap());

    for (Role role : roles) {
        System.out.println(role);
    }
```

show in the console that the relations of the database are missing. It seems that only in the active session-relations are found. After a server-reboot all relations are missing.

```
Role [id=52, label=Role 2, parents=[]]
Role [id=53, label=Role 1, parents=[]]
Role [id=54, label=Role 1, parents=[]]
Role [id=55, label=Role 2, parents=[54]]
```

I have no clue what occurs this kind of error. I use neo4j-ogm 2.1.2 and neo4j 3.1.3.

Any idea?

Comment: Also note that you will have 2 kinds of relationship between parent and child - `PARENT_OF` and `CHILD_OF` - this is usually a modeling mistake and 1 relationship is enough. The direction of the relationship should tell you the semantics - what is a parent and what is a child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result you are seeing is expected - neo4j-ogm maps what you return in your cypher query (plus what you already have in your session). If you also want related entities then return the relationship and other nodes:

```
MATCH (x)-[r]-(x2) RETURN x,r,x2
```

or if you want e.g. only parent field hydrated:

```
MATCH (x)<-[r:PARENT_OF]-(p) RETURN x,r,p
```

This will hydrate first level only. To hydrate all levels (parent of a parent) you need to use variable length path and return its nodes and relationships (returning paths directly doesn't work reliably):

```
MATCH p=(x)-[:PARENT_OF*..]-() RETURN nodes(p),rels(p)
```

Comment: Can you provide a working example? Because when i use
`      org.neo4j.ogm.model.Result result = session.query("MATCH (x)-[r]-(x2) RETURN x,r,x2", Collections.<String, Object>emptyMap(), true);  
    for (Map<String, Object> map : result) {
        System.out.println("C "+map.get("x"));
        System.out.println("R "+map.get("r"));
        System.out.println("P "+map.get("x2"));
    }`

Comment: i get C Role [id=3, label=Role 2, parents=[]]
R (2)-[PARENT_OF]->(3)
P Role [id=2, label=Role 1, parents=[]]
C Role [id=4, label=Role 2, parents=[5]]
R (5)-[CHILD_OF]->(4)
P Role [id=5, label=Role 1, parents=[]]

Comment: Sidenote: For what is OGM useful when there is no real mapping and i need speciel queries for different object-values. Is there way to get a real mapping like in hibernate or jpa?

Comment: See this part of documentation http://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/reference/#reference:session:loading-entities or e.g. this blog post https://graphaware.com/neo4j/2016/04/06/mapping-query-entities-sdn.html for examples. Mapping like in jpa happens when you use session.loadX methods, There is no concept of lazy fetching, that's why the query methods exist for cases where you need to be more specific what to get, similar to eager fetch in jpa query.

Comment: Thanks, your answer helps, but shows me that i have a lot of work to build a defined data-model with a database-interface.